# Undefined Error when Fetching API using RTK Query React/Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, undefined, rtk-query

I keep getting this same error of undefined data for multiple components in my data, it was working fine but for some reason it stops in fetching data and starts giving undefined out of the blue.

this is my store.js

```
import {configureStore, getDefaultMiddleware} from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { cryptoApi} from '../services/cryptoAPI';
import { cryptoNewsApi } from '../services/cryptoNewsApi';

export default configureStore({
    reducer: {
        [cryptoApi.reducerPath]: cryptoApi.reducer,
        [cryptoNewsApi.reducerPath]: cryptoNewsApi.reducer,
    },
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => 
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(cryptoNewsApi.middleware, cryptoApi.middleware)
});
```

Api file

```
import {createApi, fetchBaseQuery} from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'

const cryptoApiHeaders = {
'HEADERS1',
'HEADERS2',
'HEADERS3',
} // replaced the actual headers for question ;p

const baseUrl = "https://coinranking1.p.rapidapi.com/"

const createRequest = (url) => ({url,headers: cryptoApiHeaders})


export const cryptoApi = createApi({

  reducerPath: 'cryptoApi',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({baseUrl}),
  endpoints: (builder) =>({
    getCryptos: builder.query({
      query: () => createRequest('/coins'),
    })
  })
})

export const {  useGetCryptosQuery  } = cryptoApi;
```

This is my App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
import './index.scss';
import App from './App';
import store from './app/store';
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') 
);
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
  <Provider store = {store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

This is how i am trying to fetch the data

```
import { useGetCryptosQuery } from '../../services/cryptoAPI';

  const {data, isLoading, isFetching,error,isSuccess} = useGetCryptosQuery();
  const coinData = data?.data
  //When trying to access this globalStats, we get an error of undefined.
```

again, this was working fine and i made no changes to the code but now it seems to be giving undefined error.
i have used isLoading, isFetching and isSuccess in each component giving the error as such:

```
if (isLoading && isFetching) return <>Loading....</>
if(error) {console.log(error)}
```

i tried using JSON server as well and made sure the data request is coming in: [Data Coming in Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kifBs.png)
,
the image of the error: [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHyIS.png)

UPDATE:
the error seems to be while importing data :

> const {data, isLoading: isLoadingCoins} = useGetCryptosQuery();

i switched it between json server from local machine and a rapid api server but both were giving undefined.
i have tried going through the rtk query but seems like im looking in the wrong place here.
this is data getting in using rapid api: [rapidApi 200 Success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRPyN.png)

link to code: https://github.com/Raghav-rv28/crypto-metrics

Answer (score 1):

I had this error and managed to solve this you need to add middleware in the store.js after the reducer and it will work...like this

```
import { configureStore, } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { cryptoApi } from "../services/Cryptoapi";

export default configureStore({
    reducer: {
        [cryptoApi.reducerPath]:cryptoApi.reducer,
     
    },
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(cryptoApi.middleware),
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo there - the variable is called `coinsData`, but you want to access `coinData`.

Comment: i have changed the name but still the same error, its not a typo issue because all components start giving this error if run them all. in rare few cases the website starts running but all data is undefined.

Comment: Continuing with the snippet above: Why are you accessing `cryptoList?.data?.coins` when your data is in the `data` variable, declared directly above? I see no reason for `cryptoList` anywhere there

Comment: i didnt update the question properly, but no i made a typo in the question, in actual code which is on github, it is data not cryptolist

Comment: that github link leads to a project without any commits after the initial project setup

Comment: https://github.com/Raghav-rv28/crypto-metrics/tree/main

Comment: Thank you so much @phry for your help, but i figured out the answer. the rapidApi stopped giving certain data in their query and that was the reason when i went through the queries. sorry to waste your time :p cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I understand you are not subscribed to this API in Rapidapi so thought you can get another free API.

**and don't using again**

```
const {data, isLoading, isFetching,error,isSuccess} = useGetCryptosQuery();
  const coinData = data?.data
```

**It is enough to use it like this**

```
   import { useGetCryptosQuery } from '../../services/cryptoAPI';
    
      const {data: coinData, isLoading, isFetching,error,isSuccess} = useGetCryptosQuery();
      const [coin, setCoin] = useState(coinData);
      //now can been access to stats.
```

Comment: i am still learning react so i am having trouble with Async JS, which is why i was not using state, i tried a combination of useState and useEffect but ended up having calamities of error brought upon myself. the project is working now, its like everything is held up by bobby pins and staples :p

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the exact issue. This is how I resolved it. If you know/found any other solution please let me know. Also, if you know understand the logic/reason behind this error, please explain it to me.

```
const {data: cryptosList, isFetching} = useGetCryptosQuery()
  const [cryptos,setCryptos] = useState(cryptosList?.data?.coins)

  useEffect(()=>{
    if(!isFetching){
    setCryptos(cryptosList?.data?.coins)
  }
  },[isFetching])
```

Comment: I typed up the exact code above and it works, until I refresh the page and it crashes again with the following error: Uncaught Error: Warning: Middleware for RTK-Query API at reducerPath "cryptoApi" .... everything is fine until the page refresh

Answer (score -2):

I guess your baseQuery is not set correctly, now you have:

```
 baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({baseUrl}),
```

It should be:

```
 baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({baseUrl: baseUrl}),
```